# Uploading files to the server using java

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload

I have my web application made using JSP, Servlets,Java and Tom cat running on server.I want to upload a tab delimited file from the local system to a local folder in  that server so that my application can picks it up..Can anyone help me please...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Apache Commons File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)

Following are few examples : [Example 1](http://www.devsphere.com/mapping/docs/guide/upload.html) 
[Example 2](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/36-file-upload-and-download-using-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/), which makes this pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

I have written and shared the code in the gits and blogged about in the subject of [Upload a file using JSP](http://vanjikumaran.blogspot.com/2013/07/upload-file-using-jsp.html)

And underneath i am using the commons-fileupload